# Update actionbar title from child fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my mainactivity I have:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.navhostApp)
val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nvAppDrawer)
drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
```

I have a navcontroller (drawer style) as my main app navigation, and then in one of the hosted fragments another nav controller for a bottom navigation. I want to have these fragments update the action bar title but the title is only for the container fragment. Is there a way to programmatically get the actionbar to change the title?

I've tried using

requireActivity and actionBar.title but it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

And of course after posting I figure it out.

```
    val actionBar = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).supportActionBar
```

Then actionBar.title = "Title"